# how to protect a flash video from refresh？

Tags: javascript, css, flash, firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>flash video refresh</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="PlayerZone"><embed height="496" width="580" flashvars="flvid=19742822&amp;createtime=2012-4-19 13:46:33" wmode="opaque" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" quality="high" bgcolor="#000000" name="player" id="player" src="swf/mine.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></div>
<a onclick="return test();" id="test">click me popup a div,and hide the scrollbar</a>
</body>
```

the code upon：

for example,when I click the a#test button,popup a div,it's no problem,but I want to hide the scrollbar while the div popup.

I used $('html').css('overflow','hidden') in test() function,in most browsers can perform it except FF(I used FF3.6) it will refresh the flash.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268
(overflow/display/position cause this bug)

how to fix it?thank you

Comment: Did you try it in a new version of Firefox? FF3 is an old browser, no longer supported. Why you're testing your page in such a browser?

Comment: @strah I didn't try it in a new version,this bug should be fixed in newer.I tested it because this version still exist,we use it,not only me

Comment: IE6 exists, too. FF3 is quite old, Mozilla is **forcing** users to update, so I wouldn't bother if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hi thanks for asking these kind of question.

Better you use in a updated firefox version and try. if not 
     please refer this link this will help u i think. use local shared objects. 
    http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=79009
    http://flash.bigresource.com/How-to-protect-Flash-Videos-from-Being-Downloaded-KV9j8rfkn.html
    http://whatisgon.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/poking-around-in-the-firefox-cache-and-protecting-your-privacy-from-flash/
```